# Mudar CSS automaticamente a cada data

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero criar um menu que a cada dia um dos links muda o estilo usando a mesma data do computador...

Exemplo de javascript:

```js
function _getDateEnd ($element) {
  var date = new Date($element.getAttribute('data-end'));

  return !isNaN(date) ? date : new Date();
}

function _timePad (n) {
  return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
}

function _timeLeft (now, end) {
  if (now <= end) {
    var seconds = parseInt((end - now) / 1000, 10),
        minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60, 10),
        hours   = parseInt(minutes / 60, 10),
        days    = parseInt(hours / 24, 10),
        left    = '';

    seconds = seconds - (minutes * 60);
    minutes = minutes - (hours * 60);
    hours   = hours   - (days * 24);

    left += (days && days > 1) ? days + ' dias, ' : (days === 1 ? '1 dia, ' : '');
    left += (toString(hours).length) ? hours + 'h ' : '';
    left += (toString(minutes).length) ? _timePad(minutes) + 'm ' : '';
    left += _timePad(seconds) + 's';

    if (days + hours + minutes + seconds > 0) {
      return left;
    } else {
      return 'Tempo esgotado!!!!';
    }
  } else {
    return 'Tempo esgotado!!!!';
  }
}

function timeCounter ($elements) {
  $elements.forEach(function ($each) {
    $each.innerHTML = _timeLeft(new Date(), _getDateEnd($each));
  });
}

var $counters = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.counter'));

timeCounter($counters);
setInterval(function () {
  timeCounter($counters);
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
background: #000000;
color: #dddddd;
}
#menu {
width: 200px;
}
#menu li {
list-style: none;
}
#menu li a {
width: 100%;
background: #006699;
color: #ffffff;
border: 2px solid #000000;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 6px;
font-size: 20px;
}
#menu li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: #00dddd;
color: #000000;
}
#menu li.diafuturo a{
background: #112244;
color: #999999;
}
#menu li.diafuturo a:hover{
background: #112244;
color: #999999;
}
#menu li.diaatual a{
background: #990000;
color: #000000;
}
#menu li.diaatual a:hover{
background: #ffc000;
color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li class="diapassado"><a href="#">09/07/2019</a></li>

<li class="diapassado"><a href="#">10/07/2019</a></li>
<li class="diaatual"><a href="#">11/07/2019</a></li>
<li class="diafuturo"><a href="#">12/07/2019</a></li>
<li class="diafuturo"><a href="#">13/07/2019</a></li>
</ul>


</div>
<br/>
Exemplo de javascript: <span class='counter' data-end='2029-06-05T12:01:48.561Z'></span>
```

Resumindo eu tava procurando uma forma de destacar um link do menu automaticamente usando um javascript parecido, se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço, obs sou iniciante em js

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer localizar o link através do seu conteúdo (como não vi `jquery` no seu código, estou usando `javascript` puro):

```js
var dataAtual = new Date().toLocaleString('pt-br', {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'});

var elemento = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a'))
  .find(el => el.textContent === dataAtual);

elemento.parentNode.classList.add("diaatual");

var proximo = elemento.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
while (proximo != null && proximo != undefined) {
   proximo.classList.add("diafuturo");
   proximo = proximo.nextElementSibling;
}
```

```css
body {
background: #000000;
color: #dddddd;
}
#menu {
width: 200px;
}
#menu li {
list-style: none;
}
#menu li a {
width: 100%;
background: #006699;
color: #ffffff;
border: 2px solid #000000;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding: 6px;
font-size: 20px;
}
#menu li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
background: #00dddd;
color: #000000;
}
#menu li.diafuturo a{
background: #112244;
color: #999999;
}
#menu li.diafuturo a:hover{
background: #112244;
color: #999999;
}
#menu li.diaatual a{
background: #990000;
color: #000000;
}
#menu li.diaatual a:hover{
background: #ffc000;
color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="diapassado"><a href="#">09/07/2019</a></li>
    <li class="diapassado"><a href="#">10/07/2019</a></li>
    <li class="diapassado"><a href="#">11/07/2019</a></li>
    <li class="diapassado"><a href="#">12/07/2019</a></li>
    <li class="diapassado"><a href="#">13/07/2019</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**OBS**: para o teste, iniciei todos os estilos como "diapassado"

E basicamente faz o seguinte para achar o link com a data atual:

`querySelectorAll('a')` para encontrar todos os links, `Array.from` para iterar com todos os valores retornados, e o `find` para encontrar o conteúdo desejado

Dai basta adicionar a classe com `parentNode.classList.add`, lembrando que o parent é para adicioar no `li` e não no `a`.

Depois, usando o `nextElementSibling` é possível encontrar os próximos elementos `li`, e termina com o `while` para, enquanto tiver elementos, vai adicionando a classe "diafuturo"

Comment: Obrigado por responder, mas eu não expliquei direito, tipo, são um link para cada dia do mês e a data do último dia é escolhida por mim mas todos os links aparecerão normal, pra não ter o trabalho de ficar mudando todo dia para diaatual que irá destacar no estilo mesmo que eu tenha que adicionar classe diferente em todos os links, é para uma escolinha infantil

Comment: nesse caso é só mudar o valor de "dataAtual", nem que seja fixo ou manualmente e a ideia vai funcionar

Comment: eu marquei como resposta aceita porque deu certo aqui mas esqueci de um detalhe, os nomes dos links não serão datas, serão apenas números, eu até tirei o ano e mês pra ficar certo mas acontece que são numeros de 1 a 315 como posso fazer nesse caso?

Comment: 315 links e a cada dia um desses links se destaca de acordo com a data que eu escolher do final...